#  Internal working of timer

Tags: c, winapi, timer

I know QueryPerformanceCounter() can be used for timing functions. I want to know:

1-Can I increase the resolution of the timer by over-clocking the CPU (so it *ticks* faster)?

2-Basically what makes some timers more precise than others, (e.g, QueryPerformanceCounter() is more precise as compared to GetTickCount())? If there is single crystal oscillator on the motherboard , why some timers are slower as compared to others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `QueryPerformanceCounter` has very high resolution - normally less than one nanosecond. I don't see why you'd like to increase it. Overclocking will increase it, but it seems like a very weak reason for overclocking.
2. `QueryPerformanceCounter` is very accurate, but somewhat expensive and not very convenient.  
   a. It's expensive because it uses the expensive `rdtsc` instruction. Faster timers can just read an integer from memory. This integer needs to be updated, and we don't want to do it too often (1000 times a second is reasonable), so we get a very cheap timer, with low precision. That's basically `GetTickCount`.
   b. It's inconvenient because it uses units which change between computers. Sometimes it will be nanoseconds, sometimes half-nano, or other values. It makes it harder to calculate with.
   a. Another source of inconvenience is that it returns very large numbers, which may overflow when you try to do math with them, so you need to be careful.

Answer (score 1):

The timing source for QPC is machine dependent.  It is typically picked up from a frequency available somewhere in the chipset.  Whether overclocking the cpu is going to affect it is highly dependent on your motherboard design.  The simplest way is to just try it, use QueryPerformanceFrequency to see the effect.

GetTickCount is driven from an entirely different timer source, the signal that also generates the clock interrupt.  It is not very precise, 1/64 of second normally, but it is highly accurate.  Your machine contacts a time server from time to time to recalibrate the clock and adjust the clock correction factor.  Which makes it accurate to about a second over an entire year.  QPC is very precise, but not nearly as accurate.  Use it only to time short intervals.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Yes, Internally, one of the better timers is rdtsc, which does give you the clock value. Combining this with information from cpuid instruction, gives you time.

2 - The other timers rely upon various timing sources, such as the 8253 timer, for instance.

QPF is a wrapper added by Microsoft on and over what rdtsc provides. Read this article for more info:
http://www.strchr.com/performance_measurements_with_rdtsc